# Phaser.js why overlap doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I created a little scene on phaser.js

When the enemy shoots me, I have to die, but it don't work

And also, when I shoot the enemies they should die. I wrote an overlap function in code, but it doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[image: GameScene]

Why is this so, can you help me?

```
var playState = {

create: function()
{
    this.enemiesArray = [];

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    this.spacebar;
    this.spacebar = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
    this.escapeKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.ESC);

    this.ship = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.height / 2 + 300, 'ship');
    this.ship.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    this.ship.scale.setTo(0.4, 0.4);
    this.cursor = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    this.enemy = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.height / 2 - 300, 'alien');
    this.enemy.anchor.setTo(.5,.5);
    this.enemy.scale.setTo(0.4,0.4);
    game.time.events.loop(1000, this.spawnEnemy, this);
    game.time.events.loop(750, this.spawnEnemyBullet, this);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.ship, this.enemy, this.bullet, this.enemyBullet);

},

update: function()
{

    if(this.cursor.left.isDown)
    {
        this.ship.x -= 7;
    }

    for(var a = 0; a < this.enemiesArray.length; a++)
    {
        this.enemiesArray[a].x -= 2;
    }

    if(this.escapeKey.isDown)
    {
        game.state.start('menu');
    }

    if(this.cursor.right.isDown)
    {
        this.ship.x += 7;
    }

    if(this.spacebar.isDown)
    {
        this.bullet = game.add.sprite(this.ship.x, this.ship.y, 'bullet');
        this.bullet.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        this.bullet.scale.setTo(0.2,0.2);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bullet);
        this.bullet.body.velocity.y = -600;

        if(!this.bullet.inWorld)
        {
            this.bullet.kill();
        }
    }
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.enemyBullet,this.ship,this.gameOverOpenMenuScreen,null,this);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.bullet,this.enemy,this.killenemy,null,this);
},

killenemy: function()
{
    this.enemy.kill();
},

gameOverOpenMenuScreen: function()
{
    game.state.start('menu');
},

spawnEnemy: function()
{
    this.enemy = game.add.sprite(Math.random()*game.width, game.height / 2 - 300, 'alien');
    this.enemy.anchor.setTo(.5,.5);
    this.enemy.scale.setTo(0.4,0.4);

    this.enemiesArray.push(this.enemy);
},

spawnEnemyBullet: function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < this.enemiesArray.length; i++)
    {
        this.enemyBullet = game.add.sprite(this.enemiesArray[i].x, this.enemiesArray[i].y, 'bullet');
        this.enemyBullet.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        this.enemyBullet.scale.setTo(0.2,0.2);
        this.enemyBullet.angle = 180;
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.enemyBullet);
        this.enemyBullet.body.velocity.y = 600;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a group to create the bullets, but I think you should correct this first:

```
game.physics.arcade.enable([this.ship, this.enemy]);
```

Add this to your code:

```
create : function() {
   ...
   //After creating the sprites
   this.bulletPlayerTime = 0;

   this.bulletsPlayer = game.add.group();
   this.bulletsPlayer.enableBody = true;
   this.bulletsPlayer.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

   for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       var b = this.bulletsPlayer.create(0, 0, 'bullet');
       b.name = 'bullet' + i;
       b.exists = false;
       b.visible = false;
       b.checkWorldBounds = true;
       b.events.onOutOfBounds.add(function(bullet) { bullet.kill(); }, this);
   }
   ...
}

update : function() {

  ...
  if (this.spacebar.isDown) {
     this.firePlayer();
  }
  ...
}

firePlayer : function() {

   if (game.time.now > this.bulletPlayerTime) {
      bullet = bulletsPlayer.getFirstExists(false);

      if (bullet) {
        bullet.reset(this.ship.x + 6, this.ship.y - 8);
        bullet.body.velocity.y = -300;
        this.bulletPlayerTime = game.time.now + 300;
      }
   }

}
```

Now you must do the same functionality but this time with the enemies ...

You can see more [here](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-group)

Answer (score 1):

You should first group all bullets to one group:

```
const bulletsGroup = this.add.group();
```

(notice that **this** referees to the scene)

Then add each one of you bullets to the group:

```
bulletsGroup.add(<your game object>);
```

After those 2 steps you can set your overlap function. The function gets group/object for its first 2 arguments, and a callback to be invoked when an overlap occurs:

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship, bulletGroup, () => console.log('boom!'));
```